# How To use new line in a toString while it is in a JLabel?

Tags: java, string, newline, tostring

my toString is the next:

```
public String toString() {
        String partner = "DRIVE:" + getSkill(Skills.DRIVE) + (System.getProperty("line.separator")) + "VEHICLE:"
                + getSkill(Skills.VEHICLE) + (System.getProperty("line.separator")) + "ACCURACY:"
                + getSkill(Skills.ACCURACY) + (System.getProperty("line.separator")) + "WEAPONS:"
                + getSkill(Skills.WEAPONS) + (System.getProperty("line.separator")) + "REFLEX:"
                + getSkill(Skills.REFLEX) + (System.getProperty("line.separator")) + " STRATEGY:"
                + getSkill(Skills.STRATEGY) + (System.getProperty("line.separator")) + "CHARISMA:"
                + getSkill(Skills.CHARISMA) + (System.getProperty("line.separator")) + "HACKING:"
                + getSkill(Skills.HACKING) + (System.getProperty("line.separator")) + "SPEED:" 
                + getSkill(Skills.SPEED) + (System.getProperty("line.separator")) + "STEALTH:" 
                + getSkill(Skills.STEALTH) + (System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        return partner;
    }
```

I tried with \n and that is not working. Neither does this. 
I have to use a String NOT a Stringbuilder, so that is not good.
I will place this in a JLabel
I need to see this :
DRIVE : somerandomnumberwhatisalreadygenerated
VEHICLE : somerandomnumberwhatisalreadygenerated
The "<  br >" is not working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML tag like this,

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>your string goes here</html>");
```

Use line separator as `<br/>`

Comment: That is not working as I mentioned.

Comment: add starting <html> and ending </html>

Comment: and after that +"string1"+string2"+...
as usual ?

Comment: Still not working

Comment: String partner = "<html>DRIVE:" ..... + getSkill(Skills.STEALTH) +"</html>";

Comment: Works very well, will mark as duplicate! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` is the OS dependent line separator.
You can even use it `System.lineSeparator()` (without error prone string parameter).
But what you want has no relation with the OS line separators. 
You need a line separator for a SWING widget text, here a JLabel.

You could use `html` tag to perform a break line in the JLabel text with `<br/>` tag.

But you should not use the `toString()` method to create the String that you will use to set the `JLabel` text.
`toString()` is for debugging, not for the functional messages of the application.
Create rather a specific method to do it.

For example :

```
final static String HTML_BR = "<br/>";

private String createLabelMsg(MyClass myClass) {

    String partner = "<html>DRIVE:" 
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.DRIVE) + HTML_BR + "VEHICLE:"
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.VEHICLE) + HTML_BR + "ACCURACY:"
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.ACCURACY) + HTML_BR + "WEAPONS:"
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.WEAPONS) + HTML_BR + "REFLEX:"
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.REFLEX) + HTML_BR + " STRATEGY:"
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.STRATEGY) + HTML_BR + "CHARISMA:"
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.CHARISMA) + HTML_BR + "HACKING:"
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.HACKING) + HTML_BR + "SPEED:" 
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.SPEED) + HTML_BR + "STEALTH:" 
            + myClass.getSkill(Skills.STEALTH) + HTML_BR
            + "</html>";
    return partner;
}
```